# How can $_SERVER['HTTPS'] be empty when accessing over HTTPS?

Tags: php, apache, https

I am having a problem with `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` being empty when I am actually accessing a page over https.

According to the [docs for `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), this should be non-empty when accessing a page over HTTPS.

Accoding the [docs for mod_ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html)

> This module provides a lot of SSL information as additional environment variables to the SSI and CGI namespace.

Does this mean that I need to explicitly

```
SetEnv HTTPS on
```

in Apache if PHP is running as mod_php to get `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` set?

I am trying to figure out if something is wrong in my system or if I am seeing normal behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to properly use **SetEnv** in your .htaccess you need the [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) module, like:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv HTTPS on
</IfModule>
```

otherwise, the **$_SERVER["HTTPS"]** will be empty..

Comment: I tried this, but now `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` is coming as "on" even if I am not using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `SetEnv` will not work with PHP module; are you using `mod_userdir` by any chance? This may have an impact.

Alternatively, you could use this kind of detection:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'
    || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {

    $secure_connection = true;
}
```

Btw, this might also happen if you site is load balanced and the balancer runs on regular HTTP connections internally.

**Update**

I'm not sure whether `mod_userdir` always has this effect, even if it's not in use.

As for the example, instead of assigning a value to `$secure_connection` you could (make sure no one is looking) write it into `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` itself :)

Comment: No load balancer.  mod_userdir is compiled in, but not in use.  The SetEnv works; I am mainly trying to figure out if this is normal behavior or if I have an actual problem.  Unfortunately, your example doesn't work for me as there is 3rd-party code that is checking $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Comment: @MPD can't say much about how mod_userdir exactly affects it, but fwiw i've added a way to still use the example code I posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache 2.x or 1.x? I found a comment on the [PHP docs for $_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#84919) which says that it will not be set with Apache 1.